# Dirac matrices in 2 dimensions and $\gamma_5$

Tags: dirac-matrices

The gamma matrices obeying the Clifford algebra can be represented by Pauli matrices in (1+1) and in (1+2) dimensions. But is it possible to define a $\gamma_5$ in these dimensions? In the sense of an analogous way of how $\gamma_5=i \gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3$ is defined in 4D.

Comment: What do you mean by "a $\gamma_5$"? You can just write down the product of all gamma matrices regardless of dimension. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: chirality only exists in even dimensions.

Comment: Are you cool with the [general picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-dimensional_gamma_matrices)?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform How is that? Does it exist in (1+1)D right?

Comment: @CosmasZachos yeah, that kind of works for me. Following the previous comment, would, in (1+1)D, $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ constitute the Dirac matrices and $\gamma_5 = \gamma_0 \gamma_1$ the chiral one? But in (1+2)D, the Dirac matrices are $\gamma_0$, $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_5 =  \gamma_0 \gamma_1$, but no chirality matrix is present?

Comment: Right. It's easy to do the σ matrices' Clifford.